# Pass empty/noop function/lambda as default argument

Tags: python

This is my code:

```
def execute(f, *args):
    f(args)
```

I sometimes want to pass no function `f` to `execute`, so I want `f` to default to the empty function.

Comment: What error message? And why is your parameter named `function`, but you call `f`?

Comment: You probably got the error message `global name 'f' is not defined` because, well, `f` is not defined.  If you got a different error message, please specify which one (full traceback, please).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't understand very well what are you trying to do
But would something like this work for you?

```
def execute(func=None, *args, **kwargs):
    if func:
        func(*args, **kwargs)
```

You can also add an else statement to do whatever you like.

Comment: Yeah, that works. I was trying to get rid of this `if` statement.

Comment: in this if func is def func(): pass. You don't need the if. just func(*args, **kwargs)

Answer (score 13):

> The problem is that sometimes want to pass no argument to execute, so I want function to default to the empty function.

Works fine for me:

```
>>> def execute(function = lambda x: x, *args):
...   print function, args
...   function(args)
...
>>> execute()
<function <lambda> at 0x01DD1A30> ()
>>>
```

I do note that your example attempts to use `f` within the implementation, while you've called the parameter `function`. Could it really be that simple? ;)

That said, you need to understand that Python will have no way to tell that you want to skip the defaulted argument unless there are no arguments at all, so `execute(0)` cannot work as it attempts to treat `0` as a function.

Comment: Sorry, the question was terribly worded. I have rewritten it.

Comment: To make it even more generic, make it `lambda *x, **xx: None`. Now it's effectively an universal no-op function -- it accepts any number of arguments and keyword arguments.

Answer (score 8):

An anonymous function returning None is often an appropriate no-op:

```
def execute(func=lambda *a, **k: None, *args, **kwargs):
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I guess this means there isn't any shorter notation for `lambda *a, **k: None`. I tried out `func=pass`, but of course that didn't work.

Comment: This should ideally be the top answer, as it prevents a lot of headaches when passing additional arguments to ```func``` within ```execute``` (say, if one of the arguments was created within ```execute``` and not passed as a parameter). Not sure if this applies here because OP gave a very bare-bones example. Using ```func=None``` as the default is a bit messy; requiring conditionals and additional type-hinting.